# Comparative genomics: how to compare ranges of sequences

Tags: r, performance, range

I did a genome comparison between two bacteria with [VISTA](http://genome.lbl.gov/vista/index.shtml).

This tools gave me the regions of DNA sequence that are common between two bacteria, **but I am most interested in knowing which CDS's are present in one bacteria that is lacking in the second one**

By using R, I managed to use the VISTA information to generate a data.frame which includes the region (range) of bases that are exclusive to the FIRST bacteria. These regions must presumibly containing genes (CDS's) that are lacking in the second one.

```
head(rango_vacio)  # Regions (mapped bp) exclusive to the first bacteria
   V1      V2
11552   13259
13365   13263
37168   37169
.....   .....
```

By the other way, I have processed a gff file of this same bacteria to extract the CDS sequences. This dataframe contains the start and the end of each of the CDS, along the accession name of the corresponding protein

```
head(cds_TIGR4) # A list of the cds of this bacteria
startbp   endbp   accession
197       1158    NP_344444
1717      2853    NP_344445
2864      3112    NP_344446
.....     ....    .....
```

IMPORTANT: The data-frames "rango_vacio" and "cds_TIGR4" are both using the same reference as per base is concerned, so I can compare both

Now, the answer to my question should be easy to accomplish, because I only need to find what CDS's are present in each of the rango_vacio ranges using as reference the range of the CDS itself

I can do it by using a very complicated set of for loops, but I am wondering to learn from any of you if this can be accomplished by any other shorter approach

Comment: See [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) for `findOverlaps` function.

Answer (score 0):

At the very end, I believe I have found myself the method

GenomicRanges cannot be used in my case because one of my data.frame contains the cds range including the strandness. The other one only contains a range

So I used the IRange package instead.

I simplify the two data-frames, to contain the start and the end of the range and the cds. One named rango, and the other one cds

```
library(IRanges)
ir_rango <- IRanges(rango[,1], rango[,2])
ir_cds <- IRanges(cds[,1], cds[,2])
common <- findOverlaps(ir_cds, ir_rango)
common <- as.matrix(common)
unique_cds <- common[,1]
uniques <- which(duplicated(unique_cds))
uniques
```

uniques contains the row number of the corresponding range shown in ir_cds. Now I only need to extract the name of the cds